# Regular Graph Proof

Tags: graph-theory

Show that if $G$ is a connected graph that is not regular, then $G$ contains adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ such that deg $u$ does not equal deg $v$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Find two vertices $x$ and $y$ such that $\deg x\ne\deg y$. Since $G$ is connected, there is a path from $x$ to $y$. Now what?

Comment: Soryy, had the same idea as you, but I loved it too much to not write it.

Comment: Since $G$ is connected we that that there is a $u-v$ path for all vertices in $G$. Also, since $G$ is not regular we know that the minimum degree of $G$ is less than the maximum degree of $G$. Let $u$ be the minimum degree of $G$ and $v$ be the maximum degree of $G$, then traversing along this path we will get to a point where deg $u$ does not equal deg $v$. Is this the right idea?

Comment: Yes, though referring to minimum and maximum degree is overcomplicating it. If $G$ is not regular, it has two vertices with different degrees. The same argument applies to an **infinite** graph which is connected and not regular, although it does not necessarily have a maximum degree.

Answer (score 0):

$G$ is connected, so there is a path between any two vertices $a,b$ suppose the path has n vertices $a_1,a_2...a_{n-1},b$. If all adjacent vertices had same degree $d(a_1)=d(a_2)$ and $d_(a_2)=d(a_3)\dots$